# URL rewrite with .htaccess for multiple-language site (multiple variables)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some trouble here – basically because I'm having a hard time understanding excactly how htaccess works.

So, I'm builiding this site – say, example.com. This site uses url parameters to get content. To prettify the output urls I've made `example.com/index.php?slug=about-us` rewrite into `example.com/about-us/`.

To achieve this I have in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So far, so good. Now, I want to be able to view the content in other languages, say in Norwegian. No problem – so I add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?slug=$2&lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This way `example.com/index.php?slug=about-us&lang=no` is rewritten as `example.com/no/about-us/`. Yay!
However – I also want the home url, `example.com` to accept the language parameter, so I can have `example.com/no/`. But if I write:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

…this overwrites the first rule, so it won't accept the `slug` parameter on its own, anymore. I'm sure there's a simple way to do this, but after hours of googling I'm still none the wiser. Here's hoping someone will educate me! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible the way you're trying to do it since apache doesn't know when it's a language value (like `no` or `eng`) or when it's a page (like `about-us`.)

Let me explain you how I would do this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?g1=$1 [L,QSA]
```

so now if I'd go to `example.com/about-us/` then this will be the same as `example.com/index.php?g1=about-us` or the other (your language url) would be `example.com/index.php?g1=no`.

now in PHP you need to check it like this:

```
if($_GET['g1'] == "no")
    //Norwegian language
else if($_GET['g1'] == "about-us")
    //About us page
else
    //Page doesn't exist
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thank you so much!